# Symfony 2 - Doctrine, how to generate entities from database

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine, entities

I want to import my database with Doctrine, so i followed the [official doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html) here

and i used the command

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AppBundle xml
```

but with this command this is the entire base (all tables) was imported. I have many tables, a hundred, and i want use a filter with the command. How it is possible ? i search to import just few tables

Comment: You could see the help of Symfony's command with `php bin/console the:command --help`. That will list you all options and arguments waited by the command :)

Comment: ok, i'm noob, thank you i will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this please:

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AppBundle xml --filter="Yourtablename"
```

Comment: Thank you, if i use this command i have error from a other table (no primary key)... i dont understand because i use this : `console doctrine:mapping:import --force AppBundle xml --filter="MyTable_A"`

Comment: Ok i found this issue https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/441 and there is no solution, just a workaround